# What do New Opportunity, Contact buttons on Devhub Scratch org. layout do?

Tags: page-layout, salesforcedx, button, scratch-org

In the Devhub org, when you go into any scratch org., you can see below 3 buttons appear on the layout.

[image]

It doesn't seems to do anything related to scratch org in my trial Devhub instance. Also does not seems to have any related list.

No such Salesforce documentation I could find on them. Any idea why these are for, Appreciate any thoughts/official doc reference on them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if this could be the answer, In Salesforce when we create objects they are getting below [default actions on the layouts as in here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=default_actions_overview.htm&type=5).

[image]